# Wordpress admin screen is blank

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm helping a colleague to migrate his Wordpress site to another platform, but the Wordpress admin content pane is completely blank. Top and left hand nav display fine, but the content is blank.

I've tried:
- Increasing the php memory allocation
- Disabling all plugins
- Switching to default theme

No luck.

Adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

...produced the following warning:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Walker_Category_Checklist::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output) in /home2/braggler/public_html/au/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 52
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this - I've tried everything thing I can think of / Google!

Comment: If you really disabled ALL plugins, and themes, then REINSTALL wp.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue before when attempting to tweak the default(current) theme and making a mistake in obviously and important file.

Can't remember where exactly the change was, but if your problem is similar, here are a few solutions you could try:

- Check your `error_log` for errors that occur upon opening the admin panel and attempt fixing them.
- Try replacing the default (current) theme's file with the original downloaded. You can backup your current one if any changed had been made to it in case you are going to need them somehow.
- Try change the default (current) theme to one of the Wordpres's *Twenty-Eleven/Twelve/Thirteen* from the configuration table in the database to regain access to the admin panel.
- **(UPDATE)** I believe another solution could be to delete the current theme and that might load a default. But I am not sure. But it's worth checking it out, though instead of deleting the theme, you can just change it's folder name in `wp-content/themes/`.

Usually an error in the theme's `functions.php` file can cause the admin panel not to display anything. Also since that file is important at Wordpress core level (and probably loaded before the custom error display mechanism) errors are not displayed.